# Building C# console project without Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I need to create a script that produces an executable from a C# console project.

The client system where the script will be run doesn't have Visual Studio, but it has the .NET framework installed. How can it be done using a minimum or no software installation at the client place?

Does the C# compiler (csc.exe) come with .NET framework? If so, is there an environment variable for the location?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a project ready and just want to change some code and then build, check out MSBuild which is located in the `Microsoft.Net` folder under the `Windows` directory.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild "C:\Projects\MyProject.csproj" /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;outdir=C:\Projects\MyProjects\Publish\
```

(Please do not edit, leave as a single line)

... The line above broken up for readability

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild "C:\Projects\MyProject.csproj"
/p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;
outdir=C:\Projects\MyProjects\Publish\
```

*[How to determine which versions and service pack levels of the Microsoft .NET Framework are installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785)*

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't know what version of .NET framework is installed, so cannot specify a path. I have to give a script (bat?) that will be run.

Comment: @andromeda: if you don't know what version of .NET is installed, what makes you think the C# program will be written for the correct version?

Comment: Ok, if .net framework 4 is installed, will it be always at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way you can determine this. A hack would be to look at the directories listed under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net`

Comment: Thank you. One doubt, how can I set outdir to the current folder where I am executing the command?

Comment: I am doing `>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
msbuild MyProj.csproj /p:outdir=C:\Publish2\` Need to place output at the same place as .csproj file.

Comment: If you are using batch file; substitute this into the command line: e.g.: %CD%MyProj.csproj

Comment: Will this build with Nugget packages?

Answer (score 5):

If you're a Grandma, this is easily:

### 1

-- Create a `.bat` file with this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe csharp.cs
csharp.exe
```

### 2

-- Create a `.cs` file with this:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
        {
            System.Console.Clear();

            //code...

            System.Console.WriteLine("Congratulation! =D");

            //...code

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
}
```

### and run .bat file =)

Answer (score 2):

I would HIGHLY recommend [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/). It's a simple installation that allows you to run CS-Files just like batch files (.bat).

Also, it allows you to compile the CS to an EXE file (console or window) from the context menu with a simple click and if you want Visual Studio as an editor, just one click, and it works.

It's really cool, I use it quite often, and I replaced all my "complex" batch scripts with CS-Scripts.

Answer (score 1):

See *[How to programmatically compile code using the C# compiler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655)*.

Write a C# console application which takes two command line parameters: C# source file name and output .exe file name. In this program, open the C# source file, read it to a string and compile it by the way described in the article.

This console program can be used in the script that you need. A stand-alone C# compiler is not required, only the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to install [MonoDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) or [SharpDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop). You get to use the .NET compilers within a free IDE.

Other than the above it is simply a matter of installing the compilers and using Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just install [.NET Framework](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851&ei=3kpwTrruO4We-Qbe_oywCQ&usg=AFQjCNEFErAGV48QbLxIG09BPHzrdNRGxg) (CLR).

Taken from [this post](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2007/10/compiling-c-code-without-access-to-visual-studio.htm):

> The C# compiler (csc.exe) is not part of Visual Studio but comes with the Microsoft.NET framework (on my system it is available at %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727). Once I discovered the whereabouts of the compiler, compiling the code was a straightforward operation.

Please refer to this guide in order to see how to work with csc: [Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)